# I can't consume data with angular 15

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I'm tring to consume data with Angular 15. I want to acesse "content" element in this JSON but when I try to access the variable content. I can not see the elements that it has.

```
contacto.component.ts
```

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Contacto } from '../contacto';
import { ContactoService } from '../contacto.service';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { ContactoDetalheComponent } from './contacto-detalhe.component';
import { PaginaContacto } from './PaginaContacto';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-contacto',
  templateUrl: './contacto.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contacto.component.css']
})
export class ContactoComponent implements OnInit{

  formulario: FormGroup = new FormGroup('')
  contacto: Contacto
  contactos: Contacto[] = new Array
  paginaContactos: PaginaContacto[] = []
  paginaContacto: PaginaContacto = new PaginaContacto
  mensagem: string = ''
  errors: string[] = []
  colunas: string[]= ['foto', 'id', 'nome', 'email', 'favorito']
  pageSizeOptions: number[] = [5, 10, 15, 20]

  constructor(
    private contactoService: ContactoService, 
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private dialog: MatDialog){
    
    this.paginaContacto.totalElements = 0
    this.paginaContacto.pageNumber = 0
    this.paginaContacto.pageSize = 5

    this.contacto = new Contacto('','')
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  ... more code ...
  }
... more code ...

  listarContactos(page: number, size: number){
    this.contactoService
    .listar(page, size)
    .subscribe({
      next: response =>{
        
        this.contactos = response.content
   
      console.log("imprimindo o erro.")
      console.log(response)

    }, 
      error: errorResponse =>{
        console.log('Erro ao obter os contactos', errorResponse)
      }
  })
  }

... more code ...

}
```

```
contacto.service.ts
```

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Contacto } from './contacto';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment.development';
import { PaginaContacto } from './contacto/PaginaContacto';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ContactoService {

 apiUrl: string = environment.API
  constructor(private httpCliente: HttpClient) { }

... more code ..

  listar(page: number, size: number): Observable<PaginaContacto[]>{
    const params = new HttpParams()
          .set('page', page)
          .set('size', size)
          
    return this.httpCliente.get<PaginaContacto[]>(
      `${this.apiUrl}?${params}`,  
      {responseType:'json'}
    );
  }

}
```

```
PaginaContacto.ts
```

```
import { Contacto } from "../contacto"

export class PaginaContacto{
    content: Contacto[] = new Array()
    pageNumber: number = 0
    pageSize: number = 0 
    totalPages: number = 0
    totalElements: number = 0
}
```

I just tried:

```
this.contactos = response.content
this.contactos = response[:content]
this.contactos = response["content"]
this.contactos = response[0].content
this.contactos = response.map(contact => {
   return contact.content
})
```

Nothing works

This is the response from console in browser.

```json
{
    "content": [
        {
            "id": 8,
            "nome": "Vicente Simão",
            "email": "vicente@gmail.com",
            "favorito": true,
            "foto": null
        },
        {
            "id": 15,
            "nome": "Novo Adiconado",
            "email": "novo@gmail.com",
            "favorito": false,
            "foto": null
        }
    ],
    "pageable": {
        "sort": {
            "sorted": true,
            "unsorted": false,
            "empty": false
        },
        "pageNumber": 5,
        "pageSize": 2,
        "offset": 10,
        "unpaged": false,
        "paged": true
    },
    "totalPages": 7,
    "totalElements": 14,
    "last": false,
    "first": false,
    "sort": {
        "sorted": true,
        "unsorted": false,
        "empty": false
    },
    "numberOfElements": 2,
    "size": 2,
    "number": 5,
    "empty": false
}
```

Comment: I feel you forget the parenthesis (see the docs in [rxjs about observables](https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/subscribe-arguments) the recomended final. the `result.content` should be work. BTW, really, if you has not method in your classes you should use interfaces, not classes. Really you only received an object with the properties, not a new Object

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON response is an object but not an array.

For your `listar` method in `ContactoService`, it should returns an Observable of `any` or `PaginaContacto` type instead of `PaginaContacto[]`.

Note that: If you return as `Observable<PaginaContacto>`, make sure that your class' properties should map with the properties from the JSON response.

```
listar(page: number, size: number): Observable<any>{
  const params = new HttpParams()
        .set('page', page)
        .set('size', size)
          
  return this.httpCliente.get<any>(
    `${this.apiUrl}?${params}`,  
    {responseType:'json'}
  );
}
```